# What kind of viruses can be found in sperm?

Tags: human-biology

It is well known that the HIV virus can contaminate other people via sperm. But is this the only virus that sperm successfully could contain, or could for example rhinoviruses also be part of sperm?

What causes the difference if there is one?

Answer (score 1):

Those are some viruses that can exist in sperm :

- Zika : [Zika and Sexual Transmission](http://www.cdc.gov/zika/transmission/sexual-transmission.html)
- Ebola : [How Long Does the Ebola Virus Survive in Semen?](http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2014/10/how-long-ebola-sperm)
- Hepatitis C : [Hepatitis C virus detection in the semen of infected patients](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1413-86702008000500003)
- Human papillomavirus infection (HPV) : [Correlation between HPV sperm infection and male infertility](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3739240/)
- Herpes simplex : [Detection of herpes simplex virus DNA in semen of men with genital HSV-2 infection](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9918316)
- Hepatitis B : [Effects of hepatitis B virus on human semen parameters and sperm DNA integrity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24218942)

Comment: Do you know if there is a special cause for there present in sperm or is it just a matter of getting dropped by the bloodstream in the region of the organs involved by producing sperm no matter what kind of virus?

Comment: @Marijn, I think they will be within the DNA that sperm contains.

Comment: It almost looks like your children going to be a kind of virus than ?

Comment: Of course the virus normally will be inside their cells.

Comment: When I think of a virus I think it as a whole structure including membrane etc. But when it is in the DNA it is only a part of the virus. Because isn't a cell after multiple copies making of the virus exploding whereby all the viruses including membrane etc are loosed in the blood and other plasma's?

Comment: In most of the cases the explosion doesn't happen in sperm, honestly I don't know why.